# Animations aren't working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am a highschooler in an extremely basic web design class. Bored, I threw together some dropdown menus with animated arrows. I need to set max-height for the open and close animations to work with text. Closing is easy (0px), but I need to set the opening to the exact height of the object, as none doesn't work with animations. I have the following code which gets the full-sized height and then sets to 0 and then that, but the animation doesn't work. I thought it might be because of the transition delay screwing the values, but even turning that off and back on inbetween doesn't work and upon logging it gets the correct height value. What's up?

```
content.style.maxHeight = "none";
var openContentHeight = content.clientHeight;
content.style.maxHeight = "0px";
content.style.maxHeight = openContentHeight + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by setting a delay with 0. I assume there's a cooldown on setting things to prevent faulty/looped code from killing everything, and running it in what's essentially a new thread made it so the cooldown was gone.